# How can i use Gulp in my existing AngularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

My project is in angular and I want to learn gulp, so I need to use my angular project.  My angular project is client based which means there currently is no node.js server backend.  What is the best way to use it for my current project?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you using AngularJS (version 1.x), or Angular (version 2+)? What does "client based" mean?

Comment: If you want to learn gulp, then read the documentation, and start experimenting.

Comment: i am using angularjs 1x and not used node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need nodeJS and npm have installed to play with gulp. Gulp is a tool which you access from command line to run some scripts. Those scripts may build you, optimize code, generate code or run a web server.
You don't need gulp on your production server, because you can play with it on your local machine and then when everything is done, you can deploy your scripts to any web server(with or without nodejs)